# CoreData Entity Unique Attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am building an app around CoreData and have bumped into a dilemma. Hopefully has a simple solution.

I have an entity, '`Equipment`'. Each equipment object has a name and type. When selecting a type depending on the selection, I need to add more attributes to that entity, but only to that object.

So if I have an `equipment` object of type `bowl`. I want to add the attribute `containsMilk` for example. Whereas if the type is `knife`, I want to add the attribute `isBreadKnife`.

Any tips on how to do this? As you can see, not every equipment object will necessarily have the same attributes and different types require unique ones.

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: I would rephrase the question: "Unique Attributes" may be misleading, since this denotes an "indexed attribute" which is unique in the set.

Comment: Possibly you may employ *inheritance* to define subclasses of `Equipment`, like `Bowl` and `Knife`? Perhaps, is that a viable approach?

Comment: Or do you want to add "attributes" at runtime? In that case you could use a to-many relationship to an `Attribute` entity, which has `key` and `value` attributes.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper How would this differ from simply defining `Bowl` and `Knife` as entities instead of `Equipment`?

Comment: @MartinR I don't actually need to add these at runtime (although its an option) as I know what the attributes will be for each type of equipment. So is it possible to define them outside of runtime as part of my data model?

Comment: @JoshKahane: Then CouchDeveloper's suggestion might be your solution. The advantage of inheritance is that common attributes and methods are defined only once in the parent entity. The disadvantage is that Core Data creates one big table containing all attributes of all sub entities.

Comment: @JoshKahane Having a base class, lets you define another entity with a relation to the base entity `Equipment` - which actually is an "abstract" entity, and actually is either a `Bowl` or `Knife` or whatever entity derived from the base `Equipment`.

Comment: Another approach would be just have the `Equipment` entity and a `type` attribute and an `attributes` attribute which contains a set of certain attributes in an *encoded* format. The format could be for example JSON. ;) This requires a more elaborate implementation, but it will be quite efficient. The `attributes` attribute is just a string in SQLite.

Comment: If all the attributes are of type `BOOL` then why not create a single attribute holding a bit mask. Within the bitmask `bit0` represents `containsMilk`, `bit1`stands for `isBreadKnife` and so on.